# Workflow in the Experience Editor - state does not refresh

Tags: experience-editor, workflow

Using Sitecore 9.3 - just implementing workflow. In the Experience Editor, workflow commands appear in the blue information bar. They are working, but after performing any of these command: Submit, Reject, Approve, etc., the change is not reflected in the information bar until I do a full refresh of the page. It seems like the command to load this state is somehow cached, but I cant figure out how or why.

1. What command (Looking at the Network tab in the browser tools) is loading the workflow state?
2. Why is this information not updating when executing a command?

**UPDATE**

- The workflow I am using is basically a copy of the Sample Workflow
  that comes with Sitecore, but we removed the autopublish upon
  approval.
- Workflow is working, even through the Experience Editor.
  Its really only the onscreen messaging in the Experience Editor that
  is lagging.
- I dont see any errors, but that is why I was asking about
  what command gets called when I click on "Submit" to submit the
  item for approval from the Experience Editor. My suspicion is that
  the response of this command is somehow cached, but I cant figure out
  what command it is.
- As an experiment, I tried using the Sample
  Workflow, to see if maybe something was configured incorrectly on my
  workflow, but the same problem happens.

Comment: Can you add more details about the workflow that you are using and how those actions are configured and also if you have any errors happening in browser console? Have you tried to see if for example the sample workflow is working correctly as by default each workflow action should refresh the page?

Comment: Is this on your local dev?  If so, are you running Live Mode?

Comment: FACE PALM!!!! Can you add that as an answer? So I can mark it accepted.